# Mirroring a worksheet without file size increase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to perform some sort of "filtered mirror" in a workbook: if a cell does respect some conditions in worksheet #1, then it should appear in the same place in worksheet #2, else a zero appears.

The problem is I want to take into account future entries in both rows and columns of worksheet #1, therefore I am dragging my IF formula on worksheet #2 from A to ZZ and from 1 to 4000. This blows up the filesize to about 40MB.

Any suggestion to accomplish this without having such a huge file size?

Comment: Maybe place the data in a [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c).  The formula will only extend as far as the table then.

Comment: What are you using the second sheet for eventually? Maybe you could skip the sheet calculation and get to what you want in one go.

Comment: Data is already in a table, horizontally different items, vertically time (but skipping some days sometimes). I need to output in a different sheet the monthly sum of all the items, conditionally to some stoppage date that is specific for every item.
My solution is therefore to replicate the table with an IF(date>stoppage_date;0;item) and then sum by month etc in the right sheet. If you have cleaner solutions I'm eager to listen.